# Error response from daemon: network x not found

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

I'm trying to run an app in docker. There are several containers each for different services used in the app like mysql, redis, etc. After running the shell script file, the containers get created and I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: network 11bddb7d7c120ba7e465e59949a2a4983250253a7f3b6bf8c528bdfaaeec931c not found
```

Now I don't know what this network is. This network is not present in the list shown by `docker network ls` . I had not performed any prune operation before this.

Comment: You've probably changed configuration and there are containers referencing a previous network. Shut everything down then try again

Comment: @Phil Like how?

Comment: Stop and remove running containers and start again